# Retain Fragment's Main View from OnCreateView After OnDestroyView is called

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, fragment

I have a main `Activity` that contains a `ViewPager` with 4 tabs. Each tab has a `fragment` inside of it. I implement an `ActionBar.TabListener` on the main `Activity`. In the `OnTabSelected` method, I call a custom `fragment.refresh` method on the selected `fragment` so that I refresh and update the `fragment` from the server. The `refresh` method resets the data.

When I close the app and, after a while, I re-open it, and I get a `NullPointerException` on the main View returned from `OnCreateView` for the `fragment`.

My question is: **How do I retain the main view for the fragment after `OnDestroyView` is called?** Or, **How do I make sure that `refresh` is called after `OnCreateView` has been called? (Should I use a flag with a while loop)?**

Comment: If I understand your question, you cannot retain the main view or any view in Android. Sometimes the view may be recycled, and sometimes not. And you don't have control over it. You can however save data after the app exits.

Comment: Yes, you do understand it correctly. Okay, I am getting a NullPointerexception in my refresh function. Because I am referring to the main view which is obviously null.

How can I make sure that I am calling the refresh function AFTER the onCreateView function ? Do you think a while loop with a flag would do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could try putting your custom fragment.refresh() in your fragment.onResume(). This way the refresh would be automatically called before the fragment is shown to the user.

If you really want to update the fragment only when the user click on the tab you could do something like that:

```
refresh(){
   if(getActivity()!=null && !isDetached()){ // check if fragment is visible
      refreshData(); // refresh data
   }else{
      needRefresh=true; // set flag for refresh
   }
}
```

and

```
onCreate(...){
...
   if(needRefresh){
      needRefresh = false;
      refreshData();
   }
}
```

I think you should go with the first solution because i'm afraid this second solution might not be flawless.

Comment: Nice, I like both of your solutions. Regarding the first, there will the problem when a user moves from one tab's fragment to another activity, then returns. Upon returning, it will refresh the fragment since OnResume is called when the activity is visible again. But I suppose I can use a flag to detected if it is coming from that activity.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I am understanding you correctly. First your statement,

> How do I retain the main view for the fragment after OnDestroyView is
>   called?

You cannot cache the view object in memory, especially after OnDestroyView().

Answering your 2nd question, you could call your custom refresh() at an override method in Fragment like:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   refresh();
   ...
}
```

- This will ensure refresh() is called after `OnCreateView()`.
- Perhaps you want to call refresh when the user clicks on a tab. If so, you could use the proper listener like `onTabSelected`(). But it seems you're not interested in this.

Comment: This makes good sense. The only problem is that, like you said, I need to call the refresh method when onTabSelected event is called. And this actually happens if the user leaves the activity then comes back after a while. I think onTabSelected gets called when calling setCurrentItem (without the user actually pressing on the tab). So in my case, the refresh method is called before the view is constructed, and so I get the NullPointerException.